# Storing generated PDF files on the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, jspdf

Using the `jsPDF` plugin, I am creating a `.pdf` file and generating a download based on a button click. I would like to save the file onto my server instead of initiating the download. So when the button is clicked I would like the file to be saved in :

```
/tmp/uploads/pdf/example.pdf
```

I am aware I need have to use `Jquery.Ajax` to post the file to the server. However, looking at the documentation and I didn't see any support for `.pdf` as a datatype.

**My code:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#PDF", function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("result");
    var tbl = window.sessionStorage.getItem("tbl");
    var cols = [],
        data = [];

    function html() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(table, true);
        doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
        doc.save( tbl+".pdf");
    }
    html();
});
```

Based on this [xml document saving](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) example I tried the following:

```
var pdfDocument = doc.save( tbl+".pdf");
        var pdfRequest = $.ajax({
              url: "/tmp/uploads/pdf",
              processData: false,
              data: pdfDocument
            });
```

This downloaded the file instead of saving it. How can I save the file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to fix this using `FormData()`, here's how I did it:

```
$(document).on("click", "#PDF", function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("result");
    var cols = [],
        data = [];

    function html() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(table, true);
        doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
        var pdf =doc.output(); //returns raw body of resulting PDF returned as a string as per the plugin documentation.
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , pdf);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post to php Script to save to server
        xhr.send(data);

    }
    html();
});
```

**upload.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "test.pdf"; // name the file
    $file = fopen("testa/pdf/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
    fwrite($file, $data); //save data
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "No Data Sent";
}
```

The key part being `var pdf =doc.output();` where you want to get the raw pdf data.

Comment: Could you have any idea why I get other file contentent in PHP from POST 'data' variable than I send from Javascript?
I alerted data before send. And next in PHP I made echo to show $_POST['data']. Next I alerted xmlHttp.responseText and I have god something other (not "freak" chars, only regular chars and a lot of shorter).

Answer (score 21):

If your PDF contains binary data, you can get into problems if you try to transfer the PDF via string. I used the blob output format of jsPDF with success.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
// ... generate pdf here ...

// output as blob
var pdf = doc.output('blob');

var data = new FormData();
data.append('data' , pdf);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status !== 200) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}

xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
xhr.send(data);
```

Your upload.php can then use the `$_FILES` array in PHP

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['data'])) {
    // PDF is located at $_FILES['data']['tmp_name']
    // rename(...) it or send via email etc.
    $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']);
} else {
    throw new Exception("no data");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**javascript**

```
doc = new jsPDF({
         unit: 'px',
         format: 'a4'
     });
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
    var data = {};
    var base64pdf = btoa(doc.output());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'WS/FileUploadHandler.ashx',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: base64pdf,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

**FileUploadHandler.ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var jsonString = String.Empty;
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonString);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\mahmoud.hemdan\Downloads\testtest.pdf", byteArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Asp.net/C# and jQuery**:
Based on @mahmoud hemdan answer, i did for my requirement.
I did like below:

**Javascript:**

```
function createPDF(){
  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
  var u = $("#myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
  doc.addImage(u, 'JPEG', 20, 20, 250, 150);
  var base64pdf = btoa(doc.output());
  $.ajax({
      url: 'ChartPDF.aspx?pdfinput=1',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: base64pdf,
      dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

**ChartPDF.aspx.cs code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pdfinput= Request.QueryString["pdfinput"];
        if (pdfinput!= null)
        {
            var jsonString = string.Empty;
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonString);
            //Get your desired path for saving file
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\ReportPDFs\Test.pdf", byteArray);
        }
    }
```

I called up the page without any querystring parameter and the page creates the graph(Code not given for drawing the graph as it is not part of the qs.) and after that it calles createPDF() function which result in reloading the page and saving the graph as pdf file on server. Later i use the file from path.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully save jspdf file in server using jspdf, javascript and php with png image

here is the javascript

```
var doc = btoa(pdf.output());
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data", doc);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'post', 'data/test.php?name=' +name, true );
alert(data);
xhr.send(data);
```

And the php file

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){ 
 $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
 //$data = $_POST['data'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
 $fname = $name."_bell_quote.pdf"; // name the file
 $file = fopen("../quote/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
 fwrite($file, $data); //save data
 fclose($file);
 echo "Bell Quote saved";   
}
else {
 echo "No Data Sent";
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!  How do I get the file name to change to something random though instead of a form fname?