# PDF created with jsPDF won't send to python server through ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to create a PDF on client side, send it to my python server via ajax call, then send the PDF to myself via email. When I create the jsPDF object with some text:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(35, 25, "test");
```

It works, and I get the email with the populated PDF attached. When I try and add an image:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(35, 25, "test");
doc.addImage(imageDataURL, 0, 50);
```

The ajax call doesn't go through and I get an error. I have tried just having the image on the page, without the text, but the same error happens. My python controller isn't complaining, mainly because it isn't getting called. When I print the error to the console, it says the responseText is "", and status is 0.

When I download the created PDF with doc.save(), the PDF looks fine. It has the image and the text is the right positions.

My code looks like this:

Javascript:

```
checkout_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = curr_order.image_url;
    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(35, 25, "test");
    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1), 'jpeg', 0, 50);
    var pdf = doc.output();
    //doc.save();
    $.ajax('{{=URL('default', 'send_note_PDF')}}', {
        data: {
            pdf_data: pdf
        },
        Method: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            console.log('cool');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('not cool');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Python:

```
def send_note_PDF():
    pdf_data = request.vars.pdf_data
    file = open('test.pdf', 'w')
    file.write(pdf_data)
    file.close()

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'sending-email@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'receiving-email@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = 'PDF Test'
    body = "test"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

    file = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
    part = MIMEApplication(file.read(), file.name)
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file.name
    msg.attach(part)

    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('sending-email@gmail.com', 'password')
    mail.sendmail('sending-email@gmail.com', 'receiving-email@gmail.com', msg.as_string())
    mail.close()
    return 'ok'
```

Do I have to format the output of the doc before I pass it through ajax? I have tried stringifying it and parsing it on the python side. It works without the picture, but whenever that picture is added, it doesn't play nicely.

Comment: In you ajax `Method` should `method`, and in `pdf_data: pdf` you're sending the pdf data as a string rather than binary data.

Comment: @Musa I can output the doc as a blob doing var pdf = doc.output('blob'). But when I try to create the file with the blob data I get a broken file. What do I have to do with the blob data?

Comment: You would take the blob add it to a FormData object and pass that object as the data parameter in $.ajax(you also have to set processData and contentType to false). The server side has to now process multipart form data to read the file data.

Comment: @Musa Thanks for the help so far. I have been looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826687/storing-generated-pdf-files-on-the-server because they are doing the same thing I am. But they write the blob straight to the file, and when I try and do that I get an error saying, "TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object". When I leave the doc.output() as a string it works but my image still isn't there.

Comment: Where does that error occur, on the server side?

Comment: @Musa Yeah on the server side. When I try to write the blob to the file.

Comment: You'll need to change the code to read it as multipart/form-data, I don't know python so I can't help you with that part.