# JSPDF is save on the local system but i want to save it on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am using JSPDF for saving PDF file. I got this but next task is to save my PDF on the server folder, not on my local computer.My function is:

```
function generatePDFFile(elem) {
    var date = new Date();
    var filename = date.getUTCDate()+date.getTime();
    const el = document.querySelector('#divInvoiceDLG')
    el.scrollIntoView()
    $(el).css("overflow", "hidden");
    html2canvas(el, {
        useCORS: true,
        allowTaint: true,
        letterRendering: true,
        logging: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {


            var quality = [0.0, 1.0];
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("img/png",quality);
            var doc1 = new jsPDF();
            doc1.addImage(img, "JPEG", 1, 1);
            doc1.save( filename);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Use some server-side PDF library, depending on your backend language. (I'm using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/))

Comment: either generate the document server-side (assuming you can reproduce the same content server-side at some point in your process flow). Either that or find out if you can get the content of doc1 and serialise it for transmission to the server via an ajax request, instead of invoking the save() method.

Comment: You can do this using Form Data.
Please refer the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826687/storing-generated-pdf-files-on-the-server.

Comment: @MitBhatt this code is related to PHP but i am working in asp.net and jquery.

Comment: @AliImran you can ignore the server-side part if it's not relevant. But since you asked how to upload the file, the JS part of Mit's suggestion is very obviously relevant. How you deal with it in ASP.NET after it's uploaded is a separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do this with c# code.

```
%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Attachments" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Attachments : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
            string PracticeId = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("PracticeId").ToString();
            string directory = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Directory"];

            Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string savepath = context.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentsPath"] + "/" + PracticeId + "/" + directory);            

            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
            }
            string filename = newGuid + "." + postedFile.FileName.Split('.').Last();
            postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + filename);

            ResponseFile objResponse = new ResponseFile
                                            {
                                                path = newGuid + "." + filename.Split('.').Last(),
                                                fileName = postedFile.FileName
                                            };

            var jSon = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var outPut = jSon.Serialize(objResponse);
            context.Response.Write(outPut);         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```