# Window open new tab giving blank page jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Hi I am new to javascript,html,jspdf I am wondering why when I click save my pdf my pdf is saving but I wanted it to open in a new tab also I am using this code to save and open it in new tab but the new tab page only display blank page I would really appreciate advice

```
window.open(doc.save('test.pdf'), '_blank');
```

this code only save my data but open it blank page in new tab

while this another code I tried only save my pdf not open anything

```
    var datall= doc.save('test.pdf');
             doc.output('datall');  
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Comment: It seems that browsers do not support `src=data:application/pdf;...` in iframes anymore. Then I think maybe the best option to open the pdf is sending to backend using ajax and then `window.open("the_file_in_backend.pdf", "_blank")`

Comment: Can you give me some idea or any links how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Here an example using php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826687/storing-generated-pdf-files-on-the-server but the client side should be the same.