# How to send a jsPDF converted pdf file to backend server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I need to send a png file to the backend server. I converted it to pdf using jsPDF:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [210, 210]);
doc.addImage(myPngData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 210, 210);
```

Now I need to send it to the server using my old-school JQuery project:

```
$.post(url,
  {
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2,
    pdf: //pdf file goes here, will doc work?,
  },
```

But what should I really send? Cause sending `doc` just won't work? Unfortunately I cannot just send and check it as the backend is not ready yet.

Comment: Looks like you need to call `.save()` first, but it looks like it only saves to disk (node.js) - hard to tell from the very limited documentation https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output  *"A string identifying one of the possible output types."* - which are???  tsk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing generated PDF files on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826687/storing-generated-pdf-files-on-the-server)

Comment: Should be just var pdf =doc.output(); and send pdf as a value?